# Not Returning Records from Server Side Javascript Calls to DE

Tags: javascript

I have server side javascript code calling a DE and am experiencing 2 issues. I am not sure what I did incorrectly and appreciate any advice.

1. Error with Call to DE: I believe that there may be an error with this code. Sample - Platform.Function.LookupRows('Test','count','SFMC_Email_ID__c','emailId');
2. Error with Dipslaying the Data: On account of an existing requirement I need to have this all in server side Javascript.

**Background:** I am creating an email which has a dynamically sized table that is being populated by a variety of fields in a Data Extension. The number of columns is determined by a field in the DE and the number of rows is dependent on the content (there will  be a maximum of 8 rows for each column.

**Code:**

```
<script runat="server">
    var emailId = "422";
    var eventIds =    Platform.Function.LookupRows('Test','Multiple','SFMC_Email_ID__c','emailId');
    var numCol = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Test','count','SFMC_Email_ID__c','emailId'); 
    var maxCol = 3;
    var minCol = 1;
    var maxRow = 8;
    var minRow = 1;
    var numRowCol1;
    var numRowCol2;
    var numRowCol3;
    var eventIdsArray = eventIds.split(/\|/);
    var numEventIds = eventIdsArray.length;
    var eventDatesArrray;
    /*Create an array for eventDates and sort desc*/
    for (var i = 0; i < numEventIds; i++){
        var eventId = eventIdsArray[i];
        var eventDate = (Platform.Function.LookupRows('ENT.event','event_id','event_date_time','eventId').)toDate();
        if(i > 0){
            eventDatesArrray += "|"; 
        }
        eventDatesArrray += eventDate;
    }
    var sortedEventDates = eventDatesArrray.split(/\|/).sort().join(/\|/))
    var sortedEventDatesArray = sortedEventDates.split(/\|/);
    /*Get Data for table*/
    if ((numCol <= maxCol) && (numCol >= minCol)){
        var div = Math.floor(numEventIds/numCol);
        var rem = numEventIds % numCol;
        if (rem > 1){numRowCol1 = div++ && numRowCol2 = div++ && numRowCol3 = div;  
        }
        else if(rem > 0){countCol = div++ && numRowCol2 = div && numRowCol3 = div;  
        }
        else if(numCol >= numEventIds){numRowCol1 = div && numRowCol2 = div && numRowCol3 = div;    
        }
        else if(numCol == 3 && numEventIds == 2){numRowCol1 = div && numRowCol2 = div && numRowCol3 = 0;    
        }
        else if(numCol == 3 && numEventIds == 2){numRowCol1 = div && numRowCol2 = 0 && numRowCol3 = 0;
        }
        else{numRowCol1 = 0 && umRowCol2 = 0 && numRowCol3 = 0; 
        }
        numCol = numCol * 2;
        write("<table cellpadding = '2' cellspacing = '3' >");
        for(var j = 0; j < numRowCol1; j++){
            write("<tr>");
            for(var x = 0, x < numCol; x++){
                for(var y = 0, y < numEventIds; y++) {
                    eventId = eventIdsArray[y];
                    var sortedEventDate = sortedEventDatesArray[y];
                    var eventYr = sortedEventDate.getFullYear();
                    var eventMoDay = (("0" + (sortedEventDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2))+ "/" + (("0" + sortedEventDate.getDate()).slice(-2));
                    var venId = Platform.Function.LookupRows('ENT.event','event_id','ven_id','eventId');
                    var venCity = Platform.Function.LookupRows('ENT.ven','ven_id','ven_city','venId');
                    var venState = Platform.Function.LookupRows('ENT.ven','ven_id','ven_state','venId');
                    var eventLoc = venCity + ',' + venState;
                    if(y%2 == 0){
                        write("<td>" + eventMoDay + "</td>");
                        if (x == 0){
                            x = 0
                        }
                        else{
                            x = x-1;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        write("<td>" + eventLoc + "</td>"); 
                    }
                }
            write("</tr>");
            }
            if ((numCol > 2) && (numRowCol2 < numRowCol1)){
            numCol = numCol - 2;
            }
         }
    write("</table>");
    }
</script>
```

Thank you,

Allison